# Kernel crash with kernel_write

Tags: android, linux-kernel, hook, arm64

I'm trying to write syscall hooks for Linux Kernel 4.14.147 (android) and i want to write them to a file in userspace
it crashes on kernel_write but if I use printk it does print it in logs

```
static struct file *file_open(const char *path, int flags, int rights);
static int file_sync(struct file *fp);
static struct file *fp = NULL;
 
asmlinkage long (*real_sys_openat)(unsigned int, const char __user*, int, umode_t);
 
asmlinkage long new_sys_openat(unsigned int dfd, const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode) { // this will be called simultaneously so the outfile file will be around 5-10 Megabytes
    int len;
    char buff[1100] = {0}, fname[NAME_MAX] = {0};
    strncpy_from_user(fname,filename,NAME_MAX);
    len=sprintf(buff, "openat(\"%s\", %hd)\n", fname, mode);
    kernel_write(fp,buff,len,&fp->f_pos); // it crashes kernel
    file_sync(fp);
    return real_sys_openat(dfd,filename,flags,mode);
}
 
static int file_sync(struct file *fp) {
    vfs_fsync(fp, 0);
    return 0;
}
static int __init konon() {
    fp = filp_open("/data/local/tmp/openat64.log", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_LARGEFILE, 0666);
    ...
    return 0;
}
 
static void __exit konoff() {
    ...
    filp_close(fp, NULL);
}
 
module_init(konon);
module_exit(konoff);
```

```
$ cat /proc/last_kmsg
[  337.573387] -(2)[362:lmkd][<ffffffa5d7c51110>] new_sys_openat+0x110/0x198 [ophk]
[  337.574124] -(0)[378:logd.klogd][<ffffffa5d7c51110>] new_sys_openat+0x110/0x198 [ophk]                    
[  337.584186] -(1)[1225:android.io][<ffffffa5d7c51110>] new_sys_openat+0x110/0x198 [ophk]                 
[  337.588485] -(4)[1364:SyncManager][<ffffffa5d7c51110>] new_sys_openat+0x110/0x198 [ophk]                  
[  338.664934] -(0)[378:logd.klogd][<ffffffa5d7c51110>] new_sys_openat+0x110/0x198 [ophk]
```

Comment: How do you know that line crashes the kernel? Can you include the kernel error if you see one?

Comment: Post updated pls check

Comment: Is the call to `filp_open` successful? It returns an error pointer value if it fails. Check `if (IS_ERR(fp)) {` `int err = (int)PTR_ERR(fp);` `printk(KERN_ERR "filp_open failed - error %d\n", err);` ...

Comment: It's successful or the lkm won't load, like vfs_fsync isn't exported for use in LKM, how to know if a function isn't exported in LKM ?

Comment: "it's successful or the lkm won't load" - does that mean that you *are* checking the return value of the call to `filp_open`?

Comment: Yeah I did and vfs_* api is not exported to kmodules so I imported them with kallsyms_lookup_table and everything worked as expected, but how to know if a function is available in LKM or not ?

Comment: "but how to know if a function is available in LKM or not?" - You could search for `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro invocation with the given function name. Usually this invocation follows the function's definition (in the `.c` file).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother but I remember now that vfs_* api is no longer exported to LKM.